# Android disable a tab on a tablayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-tablayout

I have a fragment, which has a tab layout and a viewpager with a custom adapter
I want to "gray out", and disable the click of some of the tab items based on a condition.

How can I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

```java
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.all)).setTag("-1"));
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.newTab();

View v = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
TextView text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text1.setText(getString(R.string.all));
tab.setCustomView(v);
tabLayout.addTab(tab);
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().setSelected(true);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //Below code to add categories in Tab using Web Service
    tab = tabLayout.newTab();
    v = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tab.setTag(categoriesModel.getData().get(i).getBranch_id());
    text1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    text1.setText(categoriesModel.getData().get(i).getName());
    tab.setTag(categoriesModel.getData().get(i).getId());
    if (categoriesModel.getData().get(i).isUnAvailable()) {
        text1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HomeActivity.this, R.color.color_font_deselect));
        text1.setEnabled(false);
    }
    tab.setCustomView(v);
    tabLayout.addTab(tab);

}
```